# Table Row 2 - Email Signatures

Tags: html, signature

```html
<style type="text/css">
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
 
</style>



<table width="458" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td >
      <table width="456" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Montserrat, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="132" valign="top"  ><img src="Images/logo.png" width="116" height="96" alt="" /></td>
            <td width="324"  ><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td style="font-size:25px; color:#313131; font-weight:bold;">Brandie ??????</td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:12px; color:#666666; ">Outside Sales,</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-size:12px; color:#666666;">Lighting Controls</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td style="font-size:12px; color:#666666; padding-top:2px; line-height:18px;"><i><strong>Customers Come First </strong></i></td> <br />
              </tr>
              <tr>
               
              </tr>
            </table></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><table style="margin-top:5px; line-height:15px; border-radius:25px; border: 1px solid green; background-color:#85a838; padding:5px; "width="135%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="3%" style="padding-left:3px;"><img src="Images/phone.png" width="12" height="12" alt="" /></td>
                <td width="24%"><span style="font-size:11px; color:#FFFFFF; padding-top:6px; ">+1 (999) 999 - 9999</span></td>
                <td width="3%" style="padding-left:0px;"><img src="Images/mobile.png" width="12" height="12" alt="" /></td>
                <td width="24%"><span style="font-size:11px; color:#FFFFFF; padding-top:6px; ">+1 (9999) 9999 - 9999</span></td>
                <td width="3%"><img src="Images/email.png" width="12" height="12" alt="" /></td>
                <td width="10%"><span style="font-size:11px; color:#999999; padding-top:6px; padding-right:6px; line-height:12px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF;">unknown@examplar.ca</a></span></td> 
                <td width="2.5%"><img src="Images/globe.png" width="12" height="12" alt=""/></td>
                <td width="42%"><span style="font-size:11px; color:#999999; padding-top:6px; line-height:12px;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF;">www.examplar.ca</a></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td width="3%" style="padding-left:3px; padding-top:5px"><img src="Images/map.png" width="12" height="12" alt="" /></td>
                    <td width="24%"><span style="font-size:11px; color:#FFFFFF; padding-top:0px; ">1810 Example Road, Example, Province, S4? 2?7</span></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tbody>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I was wondering if I could get some help fixing my second row in my table. For some reason, it's not obeying the width of my table and it's going onto multiple lines, and it's affecting the first row. [I erased personal information from the image, seeing there were phone numbers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4u4v.png)

Comment: Please supply your code.

Comment: provide a snippet so we have something to work with.  change what data you need to

Comment: Ok, I just added it above.

Comment: @DCR I have added it. I am not sure if you were notified.